# Use with XMLVM to convert android app to iphone app

Tags: iphone, android

Do you know some good tutorial to use XMLVM for convert android app to iphone app??
I was watch a movie on youtube about this cross but there is not a tutorial  for this.

Thanks!
Saar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

http://xmlvm.org/documentation/

> #### Sample projects
>
> Under the folder `demo`, various demo projects exist, to test XMLVM system. This section will describe only iPhone and Android based demo projects. These demo projects can be run either from the command line, or from and IDE, such as Eclipse and Netbeans. The source code of the Java-for-the-iPhone demos is located in directory `demo/iphone/`, whereas the source code of the Android-to-iPhone demos are located in directory `demo/android/`.
>
> These are self contained projects, similar with the ones created by the XMLVM skeleton process (see below under **How to start a new project under XMLVM**).

http://xmlvm.org/slides/android2iphone-google-mtv.pdf

The example of cross-compilation include in the documentation consists on the following command:

`xmlvm --in=/foo --target=android-on-iphone --iphone-app=TheApplication`

where the directory /foo is searched recursively for *.class, *.exe, and
*.xmlvm files, and then compiling using `make` to read the `Makefile` generated by xmlvm.

From http://www.xmlvm.org/documentation/manual.pdf (page 17):

> #### 2.2.3 Using Apple’s Xcode IDE
>
> The `Makefile` generated by XMLVM can only compile and deploy the appli-
>   cation on Apple’s emulator. Given the complexity of code signing that Apple
>   requires for all native iPhone applications, you will need to use Xcode if a
>   cross-compiled Java application is to be deployed on a device. The following
>   steps explain the process of compiling an XMLVM-generated application
>   using Xcode:
>
> (list of instructions)

You will need XCode installed (there's
a nice tutorial here:
http://mobileorchard.com/how-to-make-iphone-apps-part-1-xcode-suite-and-objective-c-3/)

Comment: I know this document but I dont understand something: after that I convert my project to Xcode, how can i run the emulator of iphone on this code?

Comment: I don't really use this, but it looks like you cross-compile the project with the option --target=iphone and then compiled via make using Apple's SDK for the iPhone. So, make sure you have the iphone sdk installed before starting cross-compilations. I will add an example to the answer.

Comment: I was try to compile with the command --target=android-on-iphone  but I get error that the command unknown. so I compile with --target=-iphone so I get a directory with xcode what do do now??

Answer (score 1):

You got iPhone folder with xcode proj and other staff, now, use that files copy them to Macintosh(or iHackintosh) and build iPhone app, in regular way...