# Using XMLVM: Android to iPhone

Tags: iphone, android, cross-compiling

Related to this question: [Use with XMLVM to convert android app to iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5571902/684934)

XMLVM comes with several demo projects which I assume must work perfectly for some people.  I've been running into snags and can't find very much documentation to help me.  I've been following the documentation from the xmlvm site: http://www.xmlvm.org/documentation/manual.pdf

**My story so far** (skip down a bit for my current problem)

First of all, this is a Windows XP SP3 32-bit system.

I installed Android SDK and downloaded and installed SDK Platform Android 1.5, 1.6, 2.2, 2.3.3, 3.0.

I checked out XMLVM and built it using ant.  So far, so good. (Section 1.3 on the manual)

I tried building the android demo projects (xokoban, helloworld, afireworks).  Each one fails, complaining that it can't find my Android SDK.  It's been properly set up as described in the manual, so I open up the build.xml files to see what they're actually looking for... they're looking for "$sdk$/tools/android".  Well, the android sdk has an "android.bat" in the right spot, so I copy the batch file as just "android" and the builds run fine now.

**My current problem:**

Now I invoke XMLVM using the line

`java -Xmx1G -jar c:\xmlvm\xmlvm.jar --in=/demo/android/helloworld --target=android-on-iphone --app-name=bleh`

And I get the error

`Error: Unknown target: android-on-iphone`

So I try the same line, but with `--target=iphone`

This returns the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:306)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:159)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.xmlvm.util.FileSet$3.hasNext(FileSet.java:98)
    ...
```

In a nutshell, I'm stuck and I can't even get through the demo.  Halp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTFM.......... In fact, this part was highlighted in the "related post":

In section 2.2.3 of the manual, it clearly states that the `makefile` will only work on a Mac OS platform with the Xcode IDE.  I guess I really can't start on this project until I get the mac.